# Type of ubuntu for install ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I am a beginner, I want to install & ruby on rails on local system with ubuntu 
I want to know which type and version of ubuntu i need on local system for install ruby application developement.

Comment: before selecting OS, did you make sure your hardware(motherboard, GPU, sound card and especially mouse) does support Ruby?

Comment: @slivu, what difference does GPU, sound card and mouse make when running Ruby? If Ubuntu will install Ruby should run.

Comment: This question would probably best be asked on http://superuser.com.

Comment: @TinMan, mentioned hardware has same impact on using Ruby as the version of Ubuntu. So this was a sort of humor... "before using rails you should buy a computer and install a OS that suport it". How in the world OS version are related to Ruby?! That's sounds really crazy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, just grab the latest stable image. If you are deploying a production server, you might want to consider using one of the *Long Term Support* versions, again probably the latest one.

Unless you have a specific reason not to, on a new project with no old or unusual library usage, go for the newest stable version of ubuntu, and install everything with `apt-get`.

Comment: +1 for suggestion on using long term support versions for servers, and a good, common-sense answer.